# Playing notes for a short-necked saz with a long-necked saz

Tags: string-instruments, capos

Since I'm totally new to playing the saz I have a question regarding long-necked and short-necked saz: Can I use a book designed to teach how to play the short-necked saz with a long-necked saz or is there possible trouble due to pitch or other problems? If so, would a capo be helpful to fix the discrepancy? Thanks in advance for your help!